react native blob file from api data I need save to zip file how can do in ios
const downloadJobApplied = async (isNew = false) => {
    try {
        // Download the blob data
        const response = await RNFetchBlob.fetch('GET', `${API_URL}/business/jobsApplied?isNew=${isNew}&from=${queryParams.from}&to=${queryParams?.to}`, {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        });
        const blobData = response.data;

        // Define the path to save the file
        const timestamp = new Date().getTime(); // Get current timestamp

        const filePath = `${RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.DocumentDir}/Resume${timestamp}.zip`;


        // Save the blob data to a file
        await RNFetchBlob.fs.writeFile(filePath, blobData, 'base64');

        setIsShow("RESUME_DOWNLOAD_SUCESS")

    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error saving file: ', error);
    }
};

I have an response blob and I need save as zip in ios this code will work for android i need an suggestion how to achieve ios ,Thanks for help, I enable all permission but it not working

I could not add a comment to this question, but thought I could provide some feedback. Based on your question, you are attempting to zip a file that was downloaded from an external source using Javascript in React-Native.
Based on the code you provided, you have so far been able to download the file, create a new file with a .zip extension, base64 encode the download data, and place that data into the newly created file.
While what you are doing will create a file with a .zip extension, I cannot be certain the resulting file will be a compressed file (Is the file being downloaded a compressed file already?). Based on your code, it will simply be base64 encoded. While I am uncertain why this is code is not working on IOS, perhaps fixing the compression will resolve that issue as well.
In order to get compression working and create a true .zip file with Javascript, you will require an additional library. In this case, I have chosen JSZip.
Install library: npm install jszip
Include import: import JSZip from 'jszip';
leverage JSZip for compression:
var zip = new JSZip();
zip.file(filePath, blobData);
zip.generateAsync({type:"base64"}).then(function (content) {
     location.href="data:application/zip;base64," + content;
});

If the actual issue you are facing is that the file does not appear to get created with content on your IOS device, it could be related to an issue discussed here where new line characters were interfering with the file writing, but not throwing an error. If this is the case, you can do what was suggested in that thread and strip the new line characters from the data prior to feeding it to rn-fetch-blob. But without more troubleshooting, I cannot be certain of a solution beyond that. Hope this helps.
